# Launching GUI emacslient destroys terminal frame resizing capabilities

Tags: osx, frames, emacsclient, terminal-emacs, gui-emacs

Whenever I launch a GUI session as `$ emacsclient -c`  all the emacsclient sessions I've created with `$ emacsclient -nw -c` lose several settings. The problem only occurs right after launching a GUI session, so everything is fine when working soley from the terminal or when avoiding the use of `emacsclient`.

Now, I've already found out that you can fix some of these issues by adding to the `after-make-frame-functions` hook. However, one issue persist because it seems to be out of emacs control. Namely, whenever a terminal frame is resized (this happens frequently due to me using a tiling wm) it's doesn't properly refresh it's contents. This can be partly fixed by adding a call to `redraw-display` (or possibly `redraw-frame`) to the `after-make-frame-functions` hook, as this will tell all the existing emacs frames to update whenever a new one is made.

There is a catch to this unfortunately: `redraw-display` obviously won't get called when opening up a new window that is not emacs, say a browser window. Therefore, all my emacs sessions will eventually become all garbled up until I refresh them all manually. Does anyone know how you can tell GUI sessions not to change any/my terminal sessions, or leave alone the frame refreshing? Or should I maybe change something else, like the way emacslient spawns instances? Can I seperate my GUI and terminal sessions completely maybe?

I'm running macOS 10.3.3 and emacsclient/emacs version 25.3.1. I manage my emacs daemon with `brew services`, if that is of relevance. My GUI emacs is plain Cocoa emacs installed from brew.

Comment: Can you reproduce this without your init file? If not, you need to post your init file, preferably shrunk to the smallest part that still has the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, if I launch the daemon like `$ emacs --no-init-file --daemon=\0123,4\012` the resizing is just as bad as with my config file.

Comment: Years later, I stumble upon my own thread with a similar problem on linux. Why does emacs suck so much at resizing whenever a tiling wm asks it to? Or rather, why does resizing work only 60% of the time?